# CHECK constraint between columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

Hi I am trying to use the CHECK constraint to stop one row from being larger than the other.

```
create table myTable (
begin int(10),
end int(10),
check (begin < end)
);
```

The table is created however there is no constraint being applied when inserting rows.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be great.

Comment: is this in SQL Server? I'm just quite unsure how'd you successfullly created the table with int(10). Anyway you can check the constraint created using 'sp_help myTable'.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle etc.)?

Comment: @hallie oracle is what im using

Comment: Can you give an example of inserts that should be rejected but aren't? Your current table definition allows `NULL`s, and `NULL` treatment by constraints can surprise some people, if that's a factor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a name to the constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
   begin   NUMBER (10),
   end     NUMBER (10),
   CONSTRAINT constr_begin_end CHECK (begin < end)
);
```

Also, `begin` and `end` are keywords in `Oracle`. Avoid this in column names, variable names.